# number of Ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

The number of non-trivial ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z _{12}$ to $\mathbb Z _{28}$.

Is there any general formula for ring homomorphism between $\mathbb Z _{m}$ to $\mathbb Z _{n}$,  like we have for group homomorphism from $\mathbb Z _{m}$ to $\mathbb Z _{n}$ which is $gcd(m,n)$?

Comment: Do you mean unital rings? This is often assumed implicitly. Then you require $1\mapsto 1$, which only works if $n|m$.

Comment: This is probably answered at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-are-all-the-homomorphisms-between-the-rings-mathbbz-18-and-mathbb

Comment: yeah I agree, as I have joined this site today, so I am asking that if I need to delete this question or not as it have a solution already.

Comment: No delete button visible for you? I'm not sure when that permission arrives...

Comment: Given @analysis89's comment about, I will close this as a duplicate of the earlier question. There's no need to delete.

Comment: I would have thought that that permission was always there for the OP, no?...