# Related to ring homomorphism Question.

Tags: abstract-algebra

find the number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$

My attempt :we know that the number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_m$ into $\mathbb Z_n=  2^{[\phi(n)-\phi(n/\gcd(m,n))]}$ , where $\phi(n)$ denotes the numbers of prime divisors of positive integer n.

so by   formula we get number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_{12}$ to $\mathbb Z_{28}$ is
 $$2^{[\phi(28)-\phi(28/\gcd(12,28))]}= 2^{[\phi(28)-\phi(28/4)]}=2^{[\phi(4 \times 7)-\phi(7)]} =2^{[\phi(4) \times \phi(7)-\phi(7)\times \phi(1)]} =2^{2 \times 6 - 6\times 1}= 2^6$$

Finally i got   $2^6$  answer

is its correct ?

Comment: We have $\gcd(12, 28) = 4$. But more importantly, why not just list them all and count them directly? $2^6$ is a bit too large to be honest.

Comment: @Arthur ..Is my answer is correct?? or something missing ..i have edit also

Comment: See the duplicate linked to the duplicate: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/358324/29335 . The logic in the two is the same. It is a duplicate mutatis mutandi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Given a homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z_{12}\to\Bbb Z_{28}$, how many possibilities are there for $\phi(1)$? For each such possibility, how many different possibilities are there for the rest of $\phi$?