# A quick way to determine number of ring homomorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, factoring

Find the number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_2\times \mathbb Z_2$ to $\mathbb Z_4$.

I know that checking idempotent elements the number of ring homomorphisms is $1$. Again the number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_m$ to $\mathbb Z_n$ is given by  $2^{w(n)-w(n/\gcd(m,n))}$ , where $w(n)$ denotes the numbers of prime divisors of positive integer n.

Does there exist a quick way to determine the number of ring homomorphism from $\mathbb Z_a\times \mathbb Z_b$ to another ring $R$ ?

Can anyone suggest me ?

Comment: The formula that you give --- do you understand where it comes from, how to prove it? Maybe you could use the same logic to get a formula for the problem that you are asking about.

Comment: I don't know from where it comes ?? I only know the method by checking idempotent element..

Comment: Then I think you're best off trying to work out why that formula is true. You may find some of the discussion at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263063/the-number-of-ring-homomorphism-from-mathbbz-m-to-mathbbz-n helpful. Also maybe http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/303/what-are-all-the-homomorphisms-between-the-rings-mathbbz-18-and-mathbb.

Comment: The number of nonunital ring homomorphisms $\hom(Z_{n_1}\times\cdots Z_{n_k},R)$ equals the number of $k$-tuples of pairwise commuting idempotents of $R$ of additive orders dividing $n_1,n_2,\cdots,n_k$. One is able to count this more explicitly when $R$ is itself a direct product of $Z_n$s, but I don't see how this description is further reducible in general.